# How to access memberships in the YouTube API for your own account

Tags: java, authentication, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a small tool for a friend that queries the memberships of the own channel (the one of the friend) and exports them.

I have already found the appropriate methods in the YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/membershipsLevels/list.

On the memberships page it says that you can only make requests for your own channel and users have to fill out the [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdU2liGWbwwvacC_OXlkp9WI9cdhJwP2DJAJ_lE80cGwnmUYg/viewform) to get access.

My question now is do I need to fill this up for my friend's channel or does my friend need to do this himself to get access to the API?
Also, while reading the form I noticed things that to me (as a person who can't speak English that well and doesn't know too much about legal stuff) seems rather corporate related, which doesn't quite apply here since it's just my friend's channel.

If I fill out the form now, do I have to leave the corporate related stuff blank (put a '/') or how can I fill out the form as a private person for my friend?

Also, I noticed in the form that I need to specify the 'API Project Number' and the API Client. Where can I find these or is this just the data from the client_secret.json file (i.e. clientId and projectId)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't aim to provide legal tips. I can't help you about API precisions you asked sorry.

Comment: No-one will post official link on open platform,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.